# How to find joint cdf (cumulative distribution function)?

Tags: probability, statistics

In all other examples I'd seen, f(x,y) and boundaries are given, but my problem doesn't give that.
[image: ![enter image description here]

I'd solved for pdf f(y), but don't know how t continue from there.
[image]

I know i have to do something with $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$$ and $$f_{x,y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial ^2F_{X,Y}}{\partial x\partial y}$$, but I never learned how to do it for a problem like this.

Any thoughts on how to go about this problem? Thanks in advance.

Edit: fixed images

Comment: please fix the images for easier solving.

Answer (score 1):

The joint density $f_{X,Y} (x,y)$ does not exist. The joint distribution funntion $F_{X,Y} (x,y)$ is given by $ F_{X,Y} (x,y)=x$ if $x \leq \frac y {1-y}$ and $ F_{X,Y} (x,y)=\frac y {1-y}$ if $x \geq \frac y {1-y}$ ($0\leq x,y \leq 1$).

Comment: where did you get the x for x <= y/(1-y)  and the y/(1-y) for x >= y/(1-y) from?

Comment: $ \frac X{1+X}\leq y$ becomes $  X \leq \frac y {1-y}$. Just re-writing the inequality by mutiplying both sides by  $1+X$ and simplifying). @GrandNecro

Answer (score 1):

By basic algebra:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leqslant x, Y\leqslant y)&=\mathsf P(X\leqslant x, X/(1+X)\leqslant y)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leqslant x, X\leqslant y/(1-y))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leqslant \min\{x,y/(1-y)\})\\[0ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

You can surely do the rest.